# Integral over recurrence relationship

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations, continued-fractions

I'm interested in evaluating the following definite integral

\begin{equation}
 I_n = \int_0^{\gamma} F_n(x)\:dx
\end{equation}

Where $\gamma \gt 0$ and $F_n(x)$ is based on the [recurrence relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation):

\begin{equation}
F_{n + 1}(x) = \frac{1}{1 + F_n(x)}
\end{equation}

Here $F_0(x) = f(x)$  where $f$ is a continuous function on $\left[0,\gamma\right]$. My first task was to find a general solution for $F_n(x)$ and this is where I've become unstuck.

I started by letting $F_n(x) = \frac{\alpha_n(x)}{\beta_n(x)}$. Applying it to the recurrence relationship we have:

\begin{equation}
 F_{n + 1}(x) = \frac{\alpha_{n+1}(x)}{\beta_{n+1}(x)} = \frac{\beta_n(x)}{\alpha_n(x) + \beta_n(x)}
\end{equation}

And so we have a recurrence relationship over both $\alpha_n(x)$ and $\beta_n(x)$ with $F_0(x)  = f(x) = \frac{\alpha_0(x)}{\beta_0(x)}$.

To begin with I'm focused on $f(x) = \sec(x)$  with $\alpha_0(x) = 1$ and $\beta_0(x) = \cos(x)$ and $\gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

With a few iterations via [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) the pattern that emerges is that $F_n(x)$ takes the form:

\begin{equation}
 F_n(x) = \frac{\alpha_n(x)}{\beta_n(x)} = \frac{a_n\cos(x) + b_n}{c_n \cos(x) + d_n}
\end{equation}

Where $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n \in \mathbb{N}$ Here I would like to be able to solve for each but I'm not sure how to start.

Does anyone have any good starting points/references that I can use to begin?

**Edit**: Changed the definition of $I_n$ to have generalised upper limit of $\gamma$.

**Update** Thanks to [hypernova](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/549945/hypernova)'s comment's below, it can be seen that $\beta_n(x)$ follows a [Fibonacci Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

\begin{equation}
 \beta_{n + 1}(x) = \beta_n(x) + \alpha_n(x) = \beta_n(x) + \beta_{n - 1}(x)
\end{equation}

And so we can now represent $F_n(x)$ as:

\begin{equation}
F_n(x) = \frac{\alpha_n(x)}{\beta_n(x)} = \frac{\beta_{n-1}(x)}{\beta_n(x)}
\end{equation}
for $n \geq 2$.

For the specific example above we have:

\begin{equation}
F_n(x) = \frac{\alpha_n(x)}{\beta_n(x)} = \frac{a_{n-1}\cos(x) + b_{n-1}}{a_n \cos(x) + b_n}
\end{equation}
Where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Fibonacci Sequences with $b_0 = 0$, $b_1 = 1$ and $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 1$. We see that $a_n \gt b_n$ (this will be important later)

So, we may now evaluate the integral

\begin{equation}
I_n = \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a_{n-1}\cos(x) + b_{n-1}}{a_n \cos(x) + b_n}\:dx
\end{equation}

I will here employ the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $t = \tan\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$:

\begin{align}
I_n &= \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a_{n-1}\cos(x) + b_{n-1}}{a_n \cos(x) + b_n}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{a_{n-1}\frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} + b_{n-1}}{a_n \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} + b_n}\frac{2\:dt}{1 + t^2} \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \frac{a_{n - 1}\left(1 - t^2\right) + b_{n - 1}\left(1 + t^2\right)}{\left(1 + t^2\right)\left(a_n\left(1 - t^2\right) + b_n\left(1 + t^2\right)\right)}\:dt \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \frac{\left(b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}\right)t^2 + \left(b_{n-1} + a_{n-1}\right)}{\left(1 + t^2\right)\left(\left(b_n - a_n\right)t^2 + \left(b_n + a_n\right)\right)}\:dt \\
&= 2\left(\frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}}{b_n - a_n}\right) \int_0^1 \frac{t^2 - \theta_{n - 1}}{\left(1 + t^2\right)\left(t^2 + \theta_n\right)}\:dt
\end{align}

Where

\begin{equation}
\theta_n = \frac{b_n + a_n}{b_n - a_n}
\end{equation}

As $a_n \gt b_n \geq 0$ we see that $\theta_n \lt 0$. Hence:

\begin{align}
I_n &= 2\left(\frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}}{b_n - a_n}\right) \int_0^1 \frac{t^2 - \left|\theta_{n - 1}\right|}{\left(1 + t^2\right)\left(t^2 - \left| \theta_n\right)\right|}\:dt \\
&= 2\left(\frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}}{b_n - a_n}\right)\left[ \frac{1}{\left|\theta_n\right| + 1} \left[\left(\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| + 1 \right) \arctan(x) + \frac{\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| - \left|\theta_{n}\right|}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}}\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}} \right)\right]\right]_0^1 \\
&=2\left(\frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}}{b_n - a_n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\left|\theta_n\right| + 1} \right)\left[\left(\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| + 1 \right) \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| - \left|\theta_{n}\right|}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}}\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}} \right)\right] 
\end{align}

Note $b_n = a_{n - 1}$ and thus:

\begin{align}
I_n &=2\left(\frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n-1}}{b_n - a_n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\left|\theta_n\right| + 1} \right)\left[\left(\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| + 1 \right) \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\left|\theta_{n-1}\right| - \left|\theta_{n}\right|}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}}\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left|\theta_n\right|}} \right)\right] \\
&= \frac{a_{n - 1}}{a_n}\frac{\pi}{2} + \left[1 - \frac{a_{n + 1}\left(a_{n - 1} - a_{n - 2} \right)}{a_n\left(a_n - a_{n - 1} \right)} \right]\sqrt{\frac{a_n - a_{n - 1}}{a_{n + 1}}}\operatorname{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n - a_{n - 1}}} \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the recurrence relation is fully nonlinear, it might be better to try the first few terms with the initial condition $F_0=f$. By Mathematica, it is easy to find the general expression should be of the form
$$
F_n=\frac{a_n+b_nf}{a_n+b_n+a_nf}
$$
for $n\ge 1$, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are constants. By the recurrence relation, these constants must follow
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{n+1}\\
b_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
1&0
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_n\\
b_n
\end{array}
\right),
$$
with
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\
b_1
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Thanks to linear algebra, you may solve this Fibonacci-like $a_n$ and $b_n$ immediately.

Hope this could be somewhat helpful for you.

Comment: This is great! thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidG: You are welcome!

Comment: Would this be a pseudo styled Markov Chain?

Comment: @DavidG: You mean the $a_n$-$b_n$ relation? That's a cool idea! Maybe you can construct a Markov chain with respect to this recurrence. But it first occurred to me that $b_{n+1}=a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$, which is a Fibonacci sequence. But your idea is really a good point. Let me think about this carefully.

Comment: Re Fibonacci - Yes, I hate not picked up on that. Re Markov - please do, I hope it can be used. It just jumped out at me of being in the form of $\underline{x}^{n + 1} = A\underline{x}^n$ and thought "What about Markov?" :-) Would need to reposition $A$ to meet the Markov requirements but maybe it could be used.  I look forward any results you arrive at. Thanks again for your post.

Comment: @DavidG: You are right, modifications needed to meet the Markov requirements. Here the spectral radius of $A$ exceeds $1$, making $x_n$ diverges exponentially fast rather than being bounded as a probability. My view is that $x_n$ can be taken as, say, the number or count of something. Perhaps you remember the classical game where a frog jumps upstairs from the ground to, say, the 100-th step. Each time it could jump up either one step or two steps. Then a similar recurrence model could be employed to figure out the total number of ways the frog jump up to the 100-th step.

Comment: @DavidG: For me, it is hard to try using results from Markov chains to your original question. While there might be useful results to use, it might be hard to avoid calculating $A^n$. You may try this built-in function "JordanDecomposition" in Mathematica to figure out $P$ and $J$ such that $A=PJP^{-1}$, where $J$ is the Jordan Normal Form of $A$. Then $A^n=PJ^nP^{-1}$. $J^n$ is very easy to calculate for your question, because $J$ is 2-by-2 and upper-triangular.

Comment: If you have time read the solution as posted below. Certainly some beautiful poetry in the convergence.

Comment: @DavidG: Sure! Thanks for your message. marty cohen's solution is really beautiful. I seems to have misunderstood your expectations. While the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ diverge, their resulted $F_n$ converges. marty cohen's solution definitely clarifies. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is copied from
another answer of mine:

Let
$f_1 =  \frac{1}{1 + g(x) }
$
where
$g(x) > 0,
$,
and let
$f_n(x)
 =\frac{1}{1+f_{n-1}(x)}
$.

Then
$f_n(x)
\to \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
$.

Note:
I doubt that any of this
is original,
but this was all done
just now by me.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
f_n(x)
&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+f_{n-2}(x)}}\\
&=\frac{1+f_{n-2}(x)}{1+f_{n-2}(x)+1}\\
&=\frac{1+f_{n-2}(x)}{2+f_{n-2}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $f_{n-2}(x) > 0$
then
$\frac12 < f_n(x)
\lt 1$.

Similarly,
if $f_{n-1}(x) > 0$
then
$0 < f_n(x)
\lt 1$.

$\begin{array}\\
f_n(x)-f_{n-2}(x)
&=\dfrac{1+f_{n-2}(x)}{2+f_{n-2}(x)}-f_{n-2}(x)\\
&=\dfrac{1+f_{n-2}(x)-f_{n-2}(x)(2+f_{n-2}(x))}{2+f_{n-2}(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{1-f_{n-2}(x)-f_{n-2}^2(x)}{2+f_{n-2}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
f_n(x)+f_n^2(x)
&=\dfrac{1+f_{n-2}(x)}{2+f_{n-2}(x)}+(\dfrac{1+f_{n-2}(x)}{2+f_{n-2}(x)})^2\\
&=\dfrac{(1+f_{n-2}(x))(2+f_{n-2}(x))}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}+\dfrac{1+2f_{n-2}(x)+f_{n-2}^2(x)}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2+3f_{n-2}(x)+f_{n-2}^2(x)+1+2f_{n-2}(x)+f_{n-2}^2(x)}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{3+5f_{n-2}(x)+2f_{n-2}^2(x)}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}\\
\text{so}\\
1-f_n(x)-f_n^2(x)
&=\dfrac{4+4f_{n-2}(x)+f_{n-2}^2(x)-(3+5f_{n-2}(x)+2f_{n-2}^2(x))}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1-f_{n-2}(x)-f_{n-2}^2(x)}{(2+f_{n-2}(x))^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$1-f_n(x)-f_n^2(x)$
has the same sign as
$1-f_{n-2}(x)-f_{n-2}^2(x)$.
Also,
$|1-f_n(x)-f_n^2(x)|
\lt \frac14|1-f_{n-2}(x)-f_{n-2}^2(x)|
$
so
$|1-f_n(x)-f_n^2(x)|
\to 0$.

Let
$p(x) = 1-x-x^2$
and
$x_0 = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
$
so
$p(x_0) = 0$,
$p'(x) < 0$ for $x \ge 0$.

Since
$f_n(x) > 0$,
$f_n(x)
\to x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your post - I actually was playing around with a few different cases last night and noticed that it converged as you spoke to. I wasn't sure how to go about proving it, so thanks heaps for your post!